Problem of Infinite/Arbitrary Intersection in Topology
Problem. Consider the topology
$$
\mathscr{T}_{1} = \{ \emptyset, \mathbb{R} \} \cup \{(a, +\infty) \mid a \in \mathbb{R}\}.
$$
Is there an infinite/arbitrary  intersection of elements in $\mathscr{T}_1$ that results in a set not in $\mathscr{T}_{1}$?
I believe there isn't any such intersection because the intervals $(a, +\infty)$ always "shrink" in a way that either yields another interval of the same form or becomes $\emptyset$, both of which are elements of $\mathscr{T}_1$.

What is $\bigcap_n (-\frac 1n , \infty)$?
